# Как изменить главную страницу в вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress, веб-сайт

видел много туториалов, но они все максимум 2018 года, сейчас я просто не могу найти те вкладки, где можно изменить главную страницу.

Answer (score 0):

В админ панели в меню слева --> Настройки --> Чтение --> Вверху что-то вроде "Домашняя страница" выбрать "статическая страница" и в выпадающем списке выбрать нужною страницу.